# Is there any way to force gradle to only use https connections?

Tags: gradle, https

So repo1.maven.org doesn't support http anymore so I was wondering if I can force gradle to use https for that website or just all repos, I've tried to many things, squid proxy server to redirect all http requests to repo1.maven.org to https, i've tried setting up nginx to redirect localhost to https://repo1.maven.org and setting repo1.maven.org to localhost in hosts file, etc, etc. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle searches based on how you configured the repositories. Somewhere you have configured a HTTP route somewhere.

Gradle internally uses HTTPS: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ArtifactRepositoryContainer.java#L52..L53

So you need to update your configurations if you are manually defining repositories anywhere

You may also be using a much outdated version of Gradle. Based on looking at the git history of that file linked above, it was switched to HTTPS in [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/4e22348d55aa15fc3f91010ad37bb0d77ee5fae5#diff-f4c99484b7aa850b1927b5ef93602df1) commit and was released in v2.1.0. Highly suggested you upgrade to supported version of Gradle which is v6.2+

Comment: Would you need the build.gradle file?
Edit: Also when was that change to gradle implemented, because I'm using a gradle project from 12/09/15 11:08 PM

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to update the gradle and update it to the latest version and if it works I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: If you have something from around 2015, I used Gradle 2.2, because the latest said "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build"